# How to edit cookie with javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to use cookie and I wrote following code in javascript.

```
document.cookie = "data=12345";
alert(document.cookie);
```

And nothing changes in cookie and `alert` printed nothing so there are no cookies.

What is wrong in my code? And how to use cookies?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/htzat07t/ Are you actually calling that code?

Comment: Are you running the code in an environment that actually supports cookies? (i.e. not a `file:///` URI)

Comment: There is easy way to use cookie in javascript. You can use jquery cookie library.

Comment: @ChrisG Actually, yes. The other of code is just the function definition and variable initialization.

Comment: Try pasting that code in the browser console (default hotkey f12 for chrome) it works fine for me

Comment: @Quentin First, the browser is pretty new version of chrome. And also, it is a website which is in my computer (and opened HTML file in my computer)

Comment: "And also, it is a website which is in my computer (and opened HTML file in my computer)" — That's as clear as mud. What URL scheme are you using to access the page?

Comment: @Quentin Is URL scheme means the link-like string which is on the top of browser? If it is, file:///C:/Users/randomstring/Documents/GitHub/randomstring.github.io/game/race-car.html (randomstring is a random string).

Comment: @square1001 Did you see the second comment up there? You need to install a web server and open your page by going to `http://localhost/...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are an extension to HTTP. They are associated with a specific hostname.

When you use a `file:` scheme URL there is no hostname and you are not using HTTP.

Cookies do not work when you use a `file:` scheme URL.

Load the page over HTTP(S) instead.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you will get solution from this.

First get the library from

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/master/src/js.cookie.js

and then include it. Then to set and read and remove cookie follow bellow code.

```
1.Set cookie

   Cookies.set('name', 'value');

2.Set cookie for specific time

   Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });

3.For Current page

   Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '' });

4. Read the cookie

   Cookies.get('name');

5. Remove cookie

   Cookies.remove('name');
```

Comment: Why should using a library solve the problem? (Hint: It won't).